# How to calculate auto ACF (Auto Co relation Function) using Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, usage-statistics

Hy Every One, I have a datasheet with two fields, 
1- Date / Time
2- IMPORT

I am using CORRL but it is not calculated correctly.

[image]

AM I doing right or is there any step missing?

Requirements images: [image]

Comment: Am I doing right?

Comment: Or is there another method?

Comment: I have Google it watch you tube, but every tutor show me different method...

Comment: Trying to piece together what you mean, you are looking for an auto **correlation** function which is where you multiply and sum an array of data against a shifted version of itself and plot the result as a function of shift. Check out this page (no affiliation)  for some starters http://www.real-statistics.com/free-download/real-statistics-resource-pack/. You basically need to perform the calc sum(Ai * Bi) where Bi is a shifted version of Ai. It's tedious to set up in a spreadsheet but if you explain more what you want to do, I can give you an answer

Comment: @TroyWray bro I have updated my post with requirements that actually I want to calculate....

Comment: Is it possible to calculate it?